# Simple java type inference fails

Tags: java, generics, types, inference

I have a generic interface `ExternalState<T>` and a class implementing it :

```
public class MockState<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ExternalState<T> {
}
```

Then, I have a class extending this implementation :

```
public class LunarOccultationState extends MockState<Boolean> {
    ...
}
```

and I have the following generic method :

```
  public  <T extends Comparable<T>> StateConstraintExpression.Builder equal(List<ExternalState<T>> states, T value) {
                for(var state : states){
                    StateConstraintEqual<T> sce = StateConstraintExpression.buildEqualConstraint(state, value);
                    this.constraints.add(new StateConstraintExpression(sce));
                }
            }
            return getThis();
  }
```

But when I try to call this method :

```
equal( lunarOccultationStates, false )
```

with `lunarOccultationStates` as `List` of  `LunarOccultationState`, type inference fails.
What is difficult to understand for me is that type inference in the following method (without a list) works :

```
  public  <T extends Comparable<T>> StateConstraintExpression.Builder equal(ExternalState<T> state, T value) {
                    StateConstraintEqual<T> sce = StateConstraintExpression.buildEqualConstraint(state, value);
                    this.constraints.add(new StateConstraintExpression(sce));
            return getThis();
        }
```

Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that `List<LunarOccultationState>` is a kind of `List<ExternalState<T>>`. It is not. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) for why.

What you can do is accept a `List<? extends ExternalState<T>>` instead. This type of list does not allow you to add things to it, which is the main reason why  `List<LunarOccultationState>` is not a kind of `List<ExternalState<T>>`. But you are not adding anything to the list, so it's fine.

```
public  <T extends Comparable<T>> StateConstraintExpression.Builder equal(List<? extends ExternalState<T>> states, T value) {
    for(var state : states){
        StateConstraintEqual<T> sce = StateConstraintExpression.buildEqualConstraint(state, value);
        this.constraints.add(new StateConstraintExpression(sce));
    }
    return getThis();
}
```